# What does a group of numbers minus the average divided by the average mean?

Tags: math, signal-processing, modulation

[image]

X is a sequence of real numbers, X bar is the average of the array X, and X with subscript max is the maximum value of the array.

This is a calculation process in the code, because there is no comment, so I don't understand what it is doing.

X is the radius of a set of polar coordinates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about signal processing or math and not about programming

Comment: Looks to me as if this expression describes a sequence as well.